# Representation-finite blocks of Hopf algebras up to derived equivalence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras

> Question: Which representation-finite selfinjective algebra is derived equivalent to a block of a (finite dimensional) Hopf algebra?

Famous examples are all Brauer tree algebras. Are there more example and is there an easy classification?